# Button is coverd by Canvas when position is absolute

Tags: css, html, canvas

I want to make an animation in HTML5 **canvas** and I overlay 2 canvases one on top of the other with CSS:

```css
#viewport {
  position: relative;
}
#viewport canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
#canvas1 {
  border-color: #000000;
  border-style: groove;
  z-index: -1;
}
#canvas2 {
  background: #112233;
}
```

```html
<div id="viewport">
  <canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
</div>

<input type="text">
<input type="button" value="go">
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/thodoris12/spy1tbhu/1/

The problem is that the text field and the button are covered by the canvases which I don't want.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a height or bottom margin on the viewport div. Ex:

```
#viewport {
    position: relative;
    height:220px;
}
```

or

```
#viewport {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom:220px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ln5o3o46/)**

Since the contents of the viewport are positioned absolutely, the viewport div essentially collapses as if it has no content. By setting a height or the bottom padding you can accomplish what you're after.